# Excel duplicate row consolidation

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Could someone please help me out with this one I have no idea how to go about it.

Here is the data set

[image: data set]

I want to combine the data from each colour from each method into 1 row.

In this example `Total + Blue` has data in 2 rows but I'd like to combine them into one row.

There will only be one data point per column for each colour and method so nothing will be overwritten.

Same colours will not always be adjacent to each other.

The same colour may have many rows per method but again will only have a unique data point in each column per method and colour.

The amount of columns will also be variable (#1 to many).

Some method + colour combinations will be missing data - these can be ignored. So can any rows that do not have duplicate row data eg *Green and purple*.

Here is the ideal output.

[image]

I have been getting by using manual copy and paste rows and selecting the skip blanks option, then manually deleting the copied row.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry guys somehow stuffed up the images http://i.stack.imgur.com/AHx8F.jpg here is the data

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TxU6I.jpg and output

Answer (score 0):

This VBA code should work

```
Public Sub combineRows()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks, wks1 As Worksheet
    'Define variables
    titleRow = 1
    namecolumns = 2
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Source sheet
    Set wks1 = wkb.Sheets("Sheet2") 'Destination sheet
    'Clear the destination Sheet
    wks1.Rows.Clear
    'Count rows and columns on source sheet
    totalrows = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    totalcolumns = wks.Cells(titleRow, columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'Copy title row
    wks.Rows(titleRow).Copy wks1.Rows(titleRow)
    wks1row = titleRow + 1
    'Iterates each row on source sheet
    For i = titleRow + 1 To totalrows
        original = concnames(wks, i, namecolumns)
        totalrowswks1 = wks1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        coincidence = False
        'Check if the same name exists on Destination sheet
        For k = titleRow + 1 To totalrowswks1
            originalwks1 = concnames(wks1, k, namecolumns)
            If original = originalwks1 Then
                coincidence = True
                k = totalrowswks1
            End If
        Next k
        'If the name exists on destination skips it
        If coincidence = False Then
            'Copy the entire row to destination
            For j = 1 To totalcolumns
                wks1.Cells(wks1row, j) = wks.Cells(i, j)
            Next j
            'Check on source other rows with the same name to copy its data
            For j = i + 1 To totalrows
                other = concnames(wks, j, namecolumns)
                If other = original Then
                    For k = namecolumns + 1 To totalcolumns
                        theCell = wks.Cells(j, k)
                        If theCell <> "" Then
                            wks1.Cells(wks1row, k) = theCell
                        End If
                    Next k
                End If
            Next j
            wks1row = wks1row + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function concnames(ByVal SheetName As Worksheet, therow, thecolumns)
    'This function concatenates the values on the namecolumns to create
    'a single one string.
    'It makes very easy to compare rows.
    originalvalue = ""
    For m = 1 To thecolumns
        cellData1 = SheetName.Cells(therow, m)
        originalvalue = originalvalue & cellData1
    Next m
    concnames = originalvalue
End Function
```

Open VBA / Macros with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>, under *ThisWorkbook* insert a new *Module* and paste the code on the right side.

Check in the code that the variables `titleRow`and `namecolumns`coincide with your case, as well as the sheet names, and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Pivot table.

Drag Methods and Color to the Rows area

Drag the #'s to the Values Area

Ensure the #'s are set to compute the Sum

Format to show in Tabular Form, and Repeat All Labels

Below is one result with your data:

[image]